# Web Drivers Explained

Tags: webdriver, capybara, acceptance-testing, gherkin

Can someone explain drivers to me, in the context of application testing.

Take Capybara for instance...it says it supports multiple drivers. I am having a hard time understanding exactly what they are, and how they relate to Capybara, Gherkin, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The drivers capybara supports (rack-test driver, selenium driver, poltergeist, capybara-webkit, ...) are the code that interfaces between the Capybara API and whatever tool is being used to test (rack-test, selenium, phantomjs, qt-webkit, etc).  So when you write `page.find :css, '#abcdefg'`  the driver converts that to the correct instructions for whatever is actually driving the browser.  They have no relation to Gherkin at all.